# How to make edit function to have the previous prepopulated content

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, cs50

I am trying to make the existing content to be the initial value of the textarea (i.e what the user typed before while adding that page should show when the user wants to edit the page.) when the user clicks on the Edit button.

When I click on edit, the content previously written tends to go to the title page in the url. Can you please help show me why?

VIEWS.PY

```
class AddPageForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={
            "class": "form-control",
        })
    )

class EditPageForm(forms.Form):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={
            "class": "form-control",
        })
    )
    
def edit_page(request, title):
    entry = util.get_entry(title)
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = EditPageForm(request.POST, initial={
                "content": entry

                })
        
    else:
        form = EditPageForm(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            content = form.cleaned_data['content']
            util.save_entry(title, content)
            return redirect('encyclopedia:entrypage', title)
    return render(request, 'encyclopedia/editpage.html', {'form': form})
```

EDIT PAGE

```
{% block body %}

    <h1>Edit {{ title }}</h1>

    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% form %}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
    </form>
```

ENTRY PAGE

```
{% block body %}
        {{ content|safe }}

        <a href="{% url 'encyclopedia:editpage' title=title %}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>

{% endblock %}
```

URLS.PY

```
app_name = "encyclopedia"

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:title>", views.entry_page, name="entrypage"),
    path("search", views.search, name="search"),
    path("add_page", views.add_page, name="addpage"),
    path("edit_page/<str:title>", views.edit_page, name="editpage")

]
```

Comment: When `request.method == "GET"` don't pass `request.POST` to your form

Comment: Hello Iain, the GET is to receive the previous information typed by the customer, POST is to update the edited comment. I also tried removing request.POST, i am still having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

what's in get entry function in utils?

do something like this :-

```
entry = Model.objects.all().last()
form = EditPageForm(request.POST, initial={"content": entry.content}
```

Comment: unfortunately, this didn't work as I am using forms.Form and not models.

Comment: try sending data in context dictionary from your view to template